# How to write custom connector for Facebook Presto?

Tags: sql, connector, presto

I have setup Presto with mysql connector enabled.
Now I want to write my own connector for a special type of data source.

[Custom connector for SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929132/how-to-write-my-own-dialect-in-sqlalchemy-to-adapt-http-api/) is done. But this time, I am facing dozens of Java classes. What base classes can be used as good starting point? Which interfaces must be implemented? Maybe RawFile connector?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the developer documentation: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/connectors.html. The example HTTP connector is a good starting point.

You need to implement `ConnectorFactory`, `Connector`, `ConnectorMetadata`,
`ConnectorSplitManager`, `ConnectorHandleResolver`, and either `ConnectorRecordSetProvider` or `ConnectorPageSourceProvider` at the minimum, other classes may be needed depending on what you want to do.